# Preserve in UIView

Tags: ios, uiview

I need to know how to keep the data they contain elements of View (TextField, etc) after pressing a button that leads to another view and then return to the initial data keeping at first sight establish a price in the second defined as that price should we pay each guest, to return to the view in which the price is set, data proviamente introduced, and the total has gone ... (I try to return an array of diners).

```
ContactosViewController.h

@class ContactosViewController;

@protocol ContactosViewControllerDelegate

- (void)addItemViewController:(ContactosViewController *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSMutableArray *)item;

@end

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <ContactosViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
AltaViewController.h

@interface AltaViewController : UIViewController <ContactosViewControllerDelegate>
AltaViewController.m

-(void)addItemViewController:(ContactosViewController *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSMutableArray *)item

{
    NSString *personaString =[NSString stringWithFormat:[item objectAtIndex:0]];

    self.altaResumen.text=personaString;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I'm new to this taking references from various places, I appreciate any contribution however small.Thank you very much.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: Try to find same tutorial about protocols and delegates, then you will understand all such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is VERY hard to understand. I have the impression you have the following problem:
You have a view controller, probably set up in storyboard, that contains some interface elements (`UITextField`, etc.). The user enters something there, before he/she is shown another view controller, whose view is used to enter additional data (price, etc.). When you return from the 2nd view, you want to have the data entered in the 1st view still available.
If this is the case, you simply had to define properties of the 1st view controller, and assign the data entered to them. If the data is e.g. a `NSString`, you probably would use something like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myString;
```

Declaring them as strong (default) will keep the data alive at least until the view controller is itself deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a first UIViewController where data is entered into a textField, a button that when clicked leads to another view where additional data are allocated and once introduced back to the initial view, the back, the view has lost the data entered above.